# Restrict AWS CLI commands by linux user

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

We are looking for a way to restrict a Linux user to not run specific AWS CLI commands on an EC2 server. The reason for this need is EC2 IAM profile grants more privileges than needed. Therefore we would like to restrict users who log in server to not run a few commands. for ex:

**Allow commands:-**

```
aws s3 ...

aws iam ...
```

**Deny commands:-**

```
aws secretsmanager ...
```

Comment: Nothing you will do will be truly secure - just limit the IAM policy.

Comment: We cannot restrict the IAM policy of the EC2 IAM role which is needed by the application for calling AWS APIs. That's why we would like to restrict users to execute some cli commands based on some Linux-based restriction if possible

Comment: I don't think it is possible. I'm curious - why do users need to run CLI commands on the instance?

Comment: One less-than-ideal option is described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/436086/how-to-prevent-firewall-calls-to-aws-ec2-instance-metadata-api) that prevents non-root access to the metadata service. Applications running on the instance that require AWS credentials would have to be running as root and the logged-in user would have to be prevented from escalating their permissions to root (e.g. not in sudoers). The awscli user would have to supply their own AWS credentials e.g. through local credential profiles or environment variables.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod for the inputs. We are aware of that setup but we do not want them to completely restrict running AWS CLI commands. They should be able to run CLI commands except a few and that too using EC2 IAM role which is needed by the application to function properly.

Comment: Bottom line is that you really shouldn't even be attempting to do this. Ideally, provide these users with other mechanisms e.g. additional EC2 instances with the correct, lower-permissioned IAM role or custom API access to the resources they need.